# Reshaping repeated measures in R from next generation sequencing data

Tags: r, bioinformatics, reshape

I have the dataset in R:

```
ddat <- data.frame(gene=rep(1:4,1), ID.pat=rep(c("0", "1"), each=10), allele.freq =runif(20,min=0,max=1), SNV=round(runif(20,min=0,max=4)))

ddat

     gene ID.pat allele.freq SNV
 1     1      0  0.96841970   1
 2     2      0  0.77859462   2
 3     3      0  0.38308071   0
 4     4      0  0.03842660   4
 5     1      0  0.11313244   1
 6     2      0  0.25727911   0
 7     3      0  0.73430856   1
 8     4      0  0.93272543   0
 9     1      0  0.48698303   3
 10    2      0  0.76762848   1
 11    3      1  0.86238286   1
 12    4      1  0.87513463   2
 13    1      1  0.78232771   2
 14    2      1  0.24493196   1
 15    3      1  0.41582649   0
 16    4      1  0.49521680   4
 17    1      1  0.17983000   2
 18    2      1  0.06170987   0
 19    3      1  0.23552103   1
 20    4      1  0.26549472   0
```

I use the cast , merge and reshape function :
i.e.
cast(ddat, ID.pat ~ gene, value.var="allele.freq")

I want do have the following data frame:

```
 ID.pat   gene      SNP_0         SNP_1        SNP_2        SNP_3  ... gene_4_SNP_4
1      0    1    allele.freq   allele.freq   allele.freq  allele.freq
2      1    1    allele.freq   allele.freq   allele.freq  allele.freq
.      .    .          .            .               .          .
```

How can I modify my code so that I generate the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the `reshape2` package.

```
library(reshape2)
```

First, modify your `SNV` variable (you have it labeled it with prefix "SNP_" in your output data frame so I'll just go with it).

```
ddat$SNV <- paste0("SNP_",ddat$SNV)
```

Define a function to aggregate your results. If there are not multple values, you don't have to pass this argument to `dcast` (or you can pass `identity` to be explicit).

```
fun.aggregate <- function(x) 
  if(length(x)==0) as.character(NA) else paste(round(x,3),collapse=",")
```

Use `dcast` in `reshape2` to form your data frame into wide format:

```
dcast(ddat,ID.pat+gene~SNV,fun.aggregate,value.var="allele.freq")
```

Then your output will look like this:

```
 ID.pat gene SNP_0 SNP_1       SNP_2 SNP_3 SNP_4
1      0    1  <NA> 0.387       0.125 0.825  <NA>
2      0    2  <NA>  <NA> 0.296,0.775  <NA> 0.971
3      0    3  <NA> 0.172        <NA>  <NA> 0.873
4      0    4  0.87 0.337        <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
5      1    1  <NA>  0.49        <NA> 0.455  <NA>
6      1    2 0.169  <NA>       0.402  <NA>  <NA>
7      1    3  <NA>  <NA> 0.754,0.168 0.509  <NA>
8      1    4  <NA>  <NA>        0.86 0.737 0.625
```